# SyntaxError: invalid syntax mkdir

Tags: python, mkdir

I'm doing for having mqtt python..
I'm beginer

```
# Create a workspace directory to hold all the SDK files
mkdir sdk-workspace
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-12-5c70212e7b48>", line 2
    mkdir sdk-workspace
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what is wrong.

I want to know what is wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you using a Jupyter Notebook to create a new directory?

Comment: That's a command for your operating system's command line - but you're typing it at a Python interactive prompt, instead.

Comment: Related: [Why does "pip install" inside Python raise a SyntaxError?](/q/8548030/4518341), [syntax error when using command line in python](/q/13961140/4518341), [Getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"](/q/58937650/4518341)

Answer (score -1):

The `mkdir` (make directory) is an operating system command, not a command in Python..

If you want use it in python, try in function like this:

```
import os

os.mkdir(path, mode=0o777, *, dir_fd=None)
```